# How to write multiple newlines in racket

Tags: racket

I am new to racket and working on a program but I can't seem to figure it out. I need to create multiple newlines but it is not working.

This is what I have so far, but instead of printing 4 newlines it prints "\n" n times.

```
(define (newlines n)
   (make-string n #\newline))
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't include how you're trying to display the string that function returns, but you're probably using [`write` or `print` instead of `display`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/read-write.html).

Examples of the three:

```lisp
> (write (newlines 4))
"\n\n\n\n"
> (print (newlines 4))
"\n\n\n\n"
> (display (newlines 4))




>
```

The Racket REPL uses `print` to show the results of expressions that return values:

```lisp
> (newlines 4)
"\n\n\n\n"
```